# Javascript -transform an array of strings into a list of strings

Tags: javascript

I need to find a way to transform 
var input =`["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]` so that it becomes `"tag1", "tag2", "tag3"`

At the end I should have var output = "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" `enter code here`

I tried push, splice, join...nothing worked.

**Some words on why:** It can seem weird but I need to use some third party tool querying convention

```
object.containsAll('activities', 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')
```

So the query is failing because I can't write 
`object.containsAll('activities', input)`, as input here is an array

Comment: I know...that's why i added the "some words on why".I need to have a query that takes the items of the array to make: object.containsAll('activities', 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not *spread* the `input` array into the argument list, no transformation needed?

```
object.containsAll('activities', ...input);
```

Or, without spread:

```
const argumentsArr = input.slice(); // avoid mutating the original array
argumentsArr.unshift('activities');
object.containsAll.apply(object, argumentsArr);
```

Comment: I don't know this ... => what's the name of this technique

Comment: @Mathieu `=>` is the lambda, but it is not really related to the question. Or perhaps you mean the `...` it is the spread operator.

Comment: @Mathieu: See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: wow never knew this thing. thanks i'll try this out and will read more about these techniques

Comment: Perhaps illustrate that the spread operator is Es6 and that for backwards compat you can use ‘object.containsAll.apply(null, [‘activities’].concat(input))’

Comment: @Mathieu Just read [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).